# How to get list all items from list

Tags: robotframework

I have a webpage where this code is:

```
<select tabindex="8" id="custom_field_4" name="custom_field_4[]" size="4" multiple="multiple" xpath="1">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="green" selected="selected"> green</option>
    <option value="flashing" selected="selected"> flashing</option>
</select>
```

I need to get all the option values.

I tried
Get List Items    `//select[@name="custom_field_4[]"]` but I get the error: `List with locator \'//select[@name="custom_field_4[]/option"]\' not found.'`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/2d80899b7553d564674c891ed52a3ddc77b12b25/src/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/selectelement.py) (line 333) of the Selenium library, you can see that the `Get List Items` keyword use `list` as tag name whereas in your DOM it is `select`. It won't match.

```
def _get_select_list(self, locator):
    el = self.find_element(locator, tag='list')
    return Select(el)
```

You can get all list elements using the `Get WebElements` keyword instead like:

```
${list elements}=    Get WebElements    //select[@id='custom_field_4']/option
```

You can access the `value` attribute of each element in the returned list.

Comment: I am a newby at Robot so my question might by dumb.

When I do this;
    ${list elements}=    Get WebElements    //select[@id='custom_field_4']/option
    Log to Console  ${list elements}

Then the result is [].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SanSiets check id attribute value it might be dynamic and changed at every page refresh, it should be unique and xpath should show only one matching node

Comment: @SanSiets It means that this xpath `//select[@id='custom_field_4']/option` does not match any element. As Dev said the id `custom_field_4` might be a dynamically generated one.

Comment: @SanSiets Can you share the HTML when the `Get WebElements` returned an empty list?